# Activating a Shortcut on 'hot-corner'

Tags: applescript, shortcut

I would like to be able to mouse over to a hot-corner and bring a specific app to the front.  Seems like by default Apple does not allow this so I thought of I might be able to make a shortcut with an applescript that does this.

So my question has two parts:

1. Can I make it so that I am allowed to pick any app for a short-corner and if so, how?
2. If not, Can I run a shortcut that executes an applescript to listen for hot-corner event and if registered then open an app?

Answer (score 0):

The list of hot corner actions in System Settings is not customizable.  It’s an interesting enhancement request, though, if you feel like spending a little time with Feedback Assistant.

That said, it’s possible to write your own app that watches for hot corners or other pointer gestures, and at least one already exists: BetterTouchTool.